# Asset File is not being read correctly by InputStream/Reader

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to build my own password generator. Therefore I created files containing all symbols, which are currently lying in the manually created folder "assets". I also created a method, that shall return a single files content as a string array. The method already seems to recognize the given files because it catches no `"FileNotFoundException"` and it gets the file's amount of lines correctly. Now my problem is, that the Array returned does not contain the file's content but just an amount of `"null"s`, corresponding to the file's amount of lines.
I hope that information will do.
Can anyone help me?

I already tried using different Charsets and moving the files to the folder `"/res/raw/"`.

```
public String[] getList(String filename) {

    String[] zeichenliste = new String[0];

    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open(filename);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(is));
        int length = 0;

        while (br.readLine() != null) length++;
        zeichenliste = new String[length];

        br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(is));
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) zeichenliste[i] = br.readLine();
        br.close();
        is.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return(null);
    }
    return zeichenliste;
}
```

Comment: You're not resetting the stream's position when you iterate over it a second time (i.e.: it is at the end of the file). You should already use the captured line in the first iteration.

Comment: Side note, not related to problem: you should use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for your streams.

Comment: @Neijwiert Thanks for your side note, I'll try that.

Comment: @Neijwiert But how am I supposed to save the BufferedReader's content to an array if i don't have an array in the correct length?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you could do it. I've included notes in the code.

```
// We return a collection to:
//  1: Have a variable-length 'array' returned.
//  2: Abstract the internal implementation of the actual collection used.
// We take an InputStream, so our function is more dynamic in what way it can parse lines (i.e. not just from files)
//  Note: this won't really work on a stream that does not end.
// We renamed the function, to be more representable to what it does
public Collection<String> readAllLines(InputStream stream) 
    throws IOException // We do not handle this ourselves, since that would take away some abstraction. But it is up to you.
{
    // We're not doing try-with-resources now, because the caller owns the stream.
    // We're also passing a charset, so that we support all languages.
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    // BufferedReader has a built-in stream for all its lines.
    Stream<String> linesStream = reader.lines();

    // We collect all our lines using a built-in collector that returns it as a list.
    List<String> lines = linesStream.collect(Collectors.toList());

    return lines;
}
```

And then to call it:

```
Collection<String> lines;
try(InputStream stream = getAssets().open(filename))
{
    lines = readAllLines(stream);
}
```

As I pointed out in my comment: in your approach you tried to read passed the end of the file, as you already iterated over it once to count all lines. A [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) is a good way to solve this problem.

PS: If you do need an index based collection, then you could change the definition of `readAllLines` to return a `List` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**I solved the problem:**

```
public String[] getZeichenListe(String dateiname) {
String str = "";
try {
    InputStream is = getAssets().open(dateiname);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String buffer = "";

    while ((buffer = br.readLine()) != null) str = buffer + ";" + str;
    is.close();
    br.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return str.split(";");
```

}

Although I'm not quite sure I think the problem was that I only reinitialised the BufferedReader but not the InputStream.